# How to run Mongoose/MongoDB updates/queries in node.js backend without starting the server? (Heroku Scheduler)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I have an app hosted on Heroku (https://trendedge.app) (front-end and back-end are separate apps), and am working on implementing the Heroku Scheduler for basic tasks such as sending emails, and running updates on my MongoDB Atlas database (hit an API, update MongoDB w/ Mongoose).

For the MongoDB updates, I currently hit an admin route on the front-end, and the updates start running on the backend. Easy PZ.

To setup the Heroku scheduler, though, it requests a node.js command (seen here) ...[image: Heroku Scheduler Instructions]

... and this makes sense, but if my connection to MongoDB atlas is made upon the starting up the server ('npm start', i.e. 'node index.js'), then how do I run a node command to update MongoDB, when the server hasn't been started yet?

For example, if I run "node updateDB.js", it will error out because there is no server running, and connection to Mongo has yet to be established.

Any insight to how I can setup/test these scheduled node functions (without starting up the server?) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just create  a new connection in the file? I am sure you must mean something else

Comment: In Index.js, a lot of 'startups' occur/ are required (Express, Cors, routes, DB, config, etc.)

You are saying that in any of these new (update_XYZ_Schedule.js / email_XYZ_Schedule.js, etc.) files used for scheduling, I should make the same requirements?

My initial thought was that this seemed redundant, and there was something else that I'm missing. 

Thank you 

Comment: You can create a exported connection to do all of the stuff at one place and just call it 8n xyz file

Comment: It's possible i've been overthinking this...‍♂️ I really appreciate the quick help, going to try a few things now.

Comment: @LoganMcNulty You need to initialise a new connection for each new node process. A scheduled task will spawn a new node process so you will need to connect to mongo with that process as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can require just the necessary startups from index.js in schedule.js. In this instance just the validation and mongodb startups

Answer (score 0):

for a run single file and connect with database to perform some task. you can try this way.

```
mongodb = require('mongodb');
config = module.exports = require("/home/node/myclass/crons/config.json");

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
ObjectId = module.exports = mongodb.ObjectID;
var dbConnUrl = 'mongodb://' + config.DB_USERNAME + ':' + config.DB_PASSWORD + '@' + config.DB_HOST + ':' + config.DB_PORT + '/' + config.DB_NAME;
console.log("dbConnUrl >> ", dbConnUrl);
MongoClient.connect(dbConnUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, dclient) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("mongodb connection error >> ", err);
        process.exit();
    } else {
        db = module.exports = dclient.db();
        console.log("---------------------------mongodb connected-----------------------");
        run();
    }
});

async function run() {
    await db.collection("notification_token").find({}).toArray();
    process.exit();
}
```